# While using Selenium and chromedriver in JMeter, I get an error on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I have inherited a JMeter performance testing script. There is a chromedriver section and an HTTPSampler section. The httpsampler section works fine. The chromedriver section runs into a problem. When I run it chrome pops up like this:
[image: Chrome Error]

It does not move forward with any of the steps in the plan after that. Up until recently I've also been seeing the error

```
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

I am not seeing this now, so I don't know if it's just a difference in how the test is running or what.

The person I inherited this from was running it on a mac and did not get any of these problems. I saw it run with no errors at the same time I was getting them.

One solution I found was to add the --test-type flag to chromedriver. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to add that argument when running it through JMeter. I've tried adding both --test-type and -test-type to the end of the path to chromedriver.exe, but that did not work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Your system might have lots of Chrome.exe processes running, Kill them and try again.

Comment: Same thing happened. I actually tried that at first, I even reinstalled chrome, but unfortunately same result.

Comment: Are you using latest version of Chromedriver.exe?

Comment: Yes. I download the latest version, 2.9.something.

Comment: As per this link, chromedriver 2.29 supports only Chrome v56-58. Please check. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: I'm have chrome v57.0.2987.133 installed on my computer. So that should still be correct.

Comment: So I redownloaded chrome driver and suddenly it works. This is the 6th time I've downloaded it, and have no idea what the difference was, but it's working now. So thanks!

Comment: May i add my comment in the answer? Will you accept it :)

Comment: Abolutely. I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Done. Please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error might be due to conflict in chrome driver version. Please install the latest version of **ChromeDriver** from [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) link.

Latest version of Chrome Driver supports the browser version **v56-58**.